# recaptcha not working when converting pwa to cordova app

Tags: cordova, angular5, recaptcha

I've created a PWA(in angular 5) which uses recaptcha for the login process and then I tried converting it to cordova app, I've managed to do so using various tutorials however when the android app loads it says " invalid domain for site key", I've tried changing the name of the app to something like com.abcapp.myapp and re-configured recaptcha but the error is still there, please help